# The hook for the AJAX Add to Cart button?

Tags: posts, hooks, plugins

Anyone here ever had the need to add the AJAX add to cart button (the one located on product archives) on a custom query post output?

Do you mind sharing the hook? I can't seem to find the correct one.

Comment: Have you considered asking this in the WooCommerce support forums?

Comment: Yes, but my experience is that StackExchange is always faster.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Digging through the code, it's pretty straight-forward to find.

**First,** look at the template used for product archives - `/templates/archive-product.php`.  Among other things, it sets up the regular queries and begins building the markup of the page.

But when it actually starts looping through each product, it delegates the work to `/templates/loop-shop.php`.  This template is loaded for every product, and builds a listing using the following code:

```
<?php do_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item'); ?>
        
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">
            
    <?php do_action('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item_title', $post, $_product); ?>
            
    <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>
            
    <?php do_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', $post, $_product); ?>
        
</a>

<?php do_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', $post, $_product); ?>
```

The part we care about is the last action: `woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item`.  It's wired in `/woocommerce_template_actions.php` to the function `woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart()`.

Digging even deeper, and it looks like this function is the one you need.

### How to Add It

The easiest way to use this function is to call it directly.  Just know that it requires to parameters, `$post` and `$_product`.  The following code would call it just fine:

```
global $post; // Assuming it's already set up
$_product = &new woocommerce_product( $post->ID );

woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart( $post, $_product );
```

The function itself calls its own `echo`s, so just call it directly.

Comment: Oh, awesome! I'll give it a try.

Comment: This outputs exactly what I need, except it looks like the button must be linked to some JS, because now, when I click it, it loads the product without adding it to the cart even though the link looks like this: `{url}/?add-to-cart=9686`

Comment: That just means that the WooCommerce script files aren't being enqueued.  Take a look at /woocommerce.php` and you'll see how `woocommerce_frontend_scripts()` is being tied to the `template_redirect` hook. You'll either need to hook this into your own code or load the specific front-end scripts you need manually.

Comment: I can see it's loading the default woocommerce.min.js and related files, but the button's not caught by the `live('click')` handler. Any advice?

Comment: Without seeing your site, there's only so much advice I can give. The click handler is wrapped in another check: `if (woocommerce_params.option_ajax_add_to_cart=='yes') {` is the code getting past this?

Comment: Hi, checked that, and I got further, now it seems the $.post() doesn't get a response at all. It seems admin-ajax.php doesn't return anything.

Comment: That means the AJAX hooks aren't being added. `add_action('wp_ajax_woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_ajax_add_to_cart');` and `add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_woocommerce_add_to_cart', 'woocommerce_ajax_add_to_cart');`.  Unfortunately, without actually being hands-on with your site, there's not much more we can do to help. You'll need to hire a dev to take a look, or perhaps contact the WooCommerce team directly.

Comment: This is really dumb, but it turns out that the theme I'm using had a jQuery `click()` handler that was cutting off the AJAX request. I have changed it so it doesn't forward when the `.add_to_cart_button` is clicked, only for everything else.